# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I'm getting the following error when trying to read a SQL Job.

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `GRANT` the `SELECT` permission for the user of your job.

A simple `GRANT`.

```
USE pubs
GO

GRANT SELECT
ON authors
TO public
GO
```

Further information about [`GRANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258909%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know much about whether GRANT is needed for msdb, but I ran this script, changing 'authors' to the objects which required permission, and now all is working fine. cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You use the ["SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) in msdb (MSDN link): don't assigned permission directly, it'll be a pain to manage

And a "how to" for SSMS: ["How to: Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs (SQL Server Management Studio)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)

Note: you need a [*user* (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) in one of these roles: no need to GRANT any rights

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't overriding the default user, usually a SQL Agent Account, with a user who does not belong to the necessary role.
[image: Leave this box blank unless you need to run as a specific user, and ensure that user has all needed role memberships.]