# SELECT denied despite sysadmin privileges (policy management SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The initial situation:

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6241.0 (X64),Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on a virtual machine (clustered instance).

Under Policy Management ...

[image: Overview]

... I defined the following condition:

```
ExecuteSql('Numeric', '
USE [msdb];
SELECT [enabled]
FROM [dbo].[sysjobs]
WHERE [name] = ''updSTAT Agentur- und Bildempfangsdatum'';
')
```

The policy using this condition is active, evaluation mode is set to "On schedule".

[image: policy]

Finally I set up an alert which sends a message to an operator, if error 34052 is raised.

So far so good!

If I evaluate the policy manually, everything is working fine. If the policy is evaluated on schedule the following error is raised (error 229, severity 14 in **policy history**, not in the job agent's history):

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database
>   'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

The job which has been generated automatically has 2 steps. The 1st step named *"Verify that automation is enabled."* has type *Transact-SQL-Script*:

```
IF (msdb.dbo.fn_syspolicy_is_automation_enabled() != 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(34022, 16, 1)
    END
```

The field *Run As* is empty. As far as I know the SQL Server Agent Service Account is used. SQL Server Agent is running with an AD user account having sysadmin privileges.

On the other hand I cannot assign a proxy to subsystem T-SQL.

The second step named *"Evaluate policies."* has type *PowerShell* and is executed as SQL Server Agent Service Account.

What the heck is the problem here? What have I missed?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you sure ? `SysAdmin` ?

Comment: Yes. After all other settings failed ...

Comment: What is the ID configured during "Run As" in Job Steps?

Comment: Is the job owned by sa?

Comment: Yes, the job is owned by sa. I've added the information above.

Comment: Possible dupe with this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370881/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysjobs-database-msdb-schem

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[sysjobs] TO [AgentAcc] doesn't solve the problem. By the way the account has sysadmin privs. So it should be able to realize a simple Select. Yes, GRANT ... TO public solved the problem. But I don't want grant Select to public(!).

Comment: Did you try to trace the schedule execution and see under which specific credentials it is attempting to perform the dreaded `select`?

Comment: SQL Server Profiler confirmed that SQL Server Agent Service creds are used.